# List all empty chagelist in perforce using command line interface

Tags: perforce

I am trying to delete workspace by command 
p4 client -d

But there are some empty numbered changelist present in my workspace and not able to delete workspace

When I am trying to list all changelist using command
p4 change -s pending -u  ///...

Then empty changelist are not listed.

Is there any way to find this list through p4 command line?

Comment: Correcting command: p4 change -s pending -u //workspace-name/...

Answer (score 1):

If you use a file filter, changes without files in them will not be listed, so the "//..." and "//clientname/..." are counterproductive.  Do:

```
p4 changes -s pending -c CLIENTNAME
```

If you want to delete all those empty pending changelists, turn that output into "p4 change -d" commands like this:

```
p4 -Ztag -F "change -d %change%" changes -s pending -c CLIENTNAME | p4 -x - run
```